# AWS CodeDeploy Blue/Green deployment failure (Error code: NO_INSTANCES)

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-code-deploy

I'm trying blue/green deployment with AWS CodeDeploy.
I've set it up with to manually provision instances using an autoscaling group.

When I trigger a deploy, I see the Error code: `NO_INSTANCES`

Any advice or suggestion would be appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`NO_INSTANCES` instance indicates that either your "blue" fleet or your "green" fleet had no instances associated with them. In your deployment group, you should have your "blue" configured, and when you create the deployment, you should have the "green" fleet configured.

If you use EC2 tags, make sure that they are included in either fleet, and if you select an ASG, make sure that the ASG has capacity. Blue and green fleets are expected to be the same size as well.